# show more-show less functionality throwing error in console

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to implement show more show less functionality in my project using angular. Following are the versions of angular, bootstrap and jQuery in my project.

```
"angular": "^1.6.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"jquery": "2.2.4"
```

I have added the bower component to add this functionality. I ran following command:

```
bower install angular-read-more --save
```

I have also included the JS files.

Then I added module to the app:

```
angular.module("app", ["hm.readmore"]);
```

When I am running the project, I am getting error in browser console:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module regulationLibraryApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module hm.readmore due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'hm.readmore' is not available! You either misspelled the module name
>   or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify
>   the dependencies as the second argument.

Where I had mistaken? Is there any other easy way to implement this functionality?

Comment: show your code where you have added the js file

Comment: `'hm.readmore' is not available!`

Comment: Show how you've added the JS code. This is the most likely mistake. Check in your browser tools that the all the required JS files are actually loaded on the page.

Comment: Make sure you added the 'hm.readmore' js file before your module definition file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your bower dependencies are not loaded before angular application is bootstrapped.

Load your bower dependencies before you load angular app.

For example

```
   <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/bower_components/angular-read-more/readmore.min.js">  </script>
   <script src="/my_angular_app/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probability missing ngAnimate dependency.

To get it work 'hm.readmore' uses: ngSanitize, ngAnimate both plugins.

So, you can download it from npm repository https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-animate